# Can't ping directly connected SRX210 (Juniper)

Tags: routing, juniper, juniper-srx, srx

I'm coming to terms with JunOS, and I have set up a lab that includes two SRX210s. I have set ge-0/0/1 on both devices to:

```
ge-0/0/1 {
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        address 20.0.0.1/24;
    }
}
```

.1 on SRX1 and .2 on SRX2. Because they are directly connected and on the same subnet, a route should be visible, but when I perform a show route, I don't see anything. Perhaps I am missing something here? Am I making some stupid, rookie mistake that I will later be forced to kick myself over?

Further details: Not even learning a mac over these interfaces, but I do if I use family ethernet-switching instead.

Thanks to anyone with any idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In junos it is not enough to just assign IP to the interface to be functional , for interface to be pinable you need to do the below :

1. assign the interface for security zone : 
   EX: set security zones security-zone untrust interfaces ge-0/0/1.0
2. you have to enable ping in the security zone : 
   EX: set security zones security zone host inbound traffic system services  ping

Comment: That's what I was missing. I tried to delete the whole security section at the start as I didn't want the srx to function as a firewall. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to run SRX as a router you need to change it to packet mode, so you have to delete all the security configuration and run below command:
set security forwarding-options family mpls mode packet-based 
and then commit